# Java varargs method with single null argument

Tags: java

I have a method taking a String varargs param `locationIds`, in which there's `for loop` on the ids

```java
public static void validateLocationIds(String... locationIds) {
    for (String locationId : locationIds) {
        // do sth
    }
}
```

Now if I call `validateLocationIds(var)` where `var` of type `String` and value `null`, I expect NPE from the `for loop` because you can't do that on a null. And this is approved when I execute it from Intellij's Evaluate Expression while debugging, as it gave me NPE and the cause `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local1>" is null`.

However when the code is executed not from Evaluate Expression, there's no NPE and everything works fine.
Through debugging I found out it's because instead of being `null`, `locationIds` is converted to type `String[1]`, value `[null]`, making it possible to be processed by `for loop`.

So I'm confused how Java manged to convert `null` to `[null]`, and why Evaluate Expression failed to do so.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen if you do `String var = null; validateLocationIds(var)` and use Intellij's Evaluate Expression to call the code, it's treating `locationIds` as `null`. At least according to the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about `null` specifically, it's about the `null` expression's type.

A null expression doesn't have to be typed, but it can be. Here is a trivial example:

```
String x = null;
System.out.println(x);
```

This is very slightly different compared to:

```
System.out.println(null);
```

Note that `println` has a boatload of overloads - completely different methods (and `javac`, the compiler, *must* pick which exact overload to invoke **at compile time**), that are all named `println`, all of which have 1 parameter. The first snippet is easy for the compiler: You clearly mean to call that `println` that takes a single String as parameter. However, the second is ambiguous. If I attempt to compile the second snippet, the compiler will literally tell me so:

> error: reference to println is ambiguous

This shows how, even though the runtime behaviour of this would seem to be 100% identical (both `null` and `x` are expressions whose value will definitely be `null`), turns out, at least at compile time, this is not true.

The same principle can explain what you see here, with your varargs, in a slightly different way. Given:

```
void validateLocationIds(String... locationIds) {
```

That's just syntax sugar. Specifically, it's syntax sugar for:

- The method's signature is `validateLocationIds(String[] locationIds)`.
- However, you are telling the compiler, during the compilation of **calls** to this method, to treat a sequence of arguments that can all be treated as `String` arguments to go ahead and treat that as if the caller had written `validateLocationIds(new String[] {a, b, c})` instead of what you typed (`validateLocationIds(a, b, c);`).

**Crucially** the compiler will **only** do that if it **has to** - if the code would not compile if it didn't do this 'fold the args into an array'.

This then gets us (presumably, there are some more exotic alternate explanations, this is merely the most likely) to an explanation. Given:

```
String x = null;
validateLocationIds(x);
```

There is **only one** way for the compiler to make this work: By treating `x` as a `String` and therefore syntax sugaring that into `new String[] {x}`, i.e. a new string array of size 1 whose first and only entry is `null`. Because otherwise it would not compile; a variable of type `String` simply isn't a `String[]`. Even if the variable's value is currently `null` which is also a valid value for `String[]` - because how could the compiler possibly know that for sure? It can't, so it won't just go: Oohhh,, I see, a variable of type `String`, but, I know its `null` so I can treat it as whatever the heck I want, really. It does *not* do that.

In contrast to spelling it out literally:

```
validateLocationIds(null);
```

This is *not* ambiguous, unlike our println example: The Java Language Spec, in the section on picking between multiple different overloads, explicitly states that the compiler must error out with a 'call is ambiguous' error, **but**, when it's about whether to apply varargs sugaring or not, **that is not the case**: The array "wins", so to speak. In other words, if the call could *both* be treated as a straight method call (the expression *is* the array), *as well as* sugaring into an array (you could zip that one arg into a 1-len array and pass that instead), then 'just treat as array' wins.

This makes sense. Imagine that would be an error condition. Then you could NEVER pass an object array to `void foo(Object...)`. After all, an array -is also an object-, and could therefore be 'zipped'.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm running openjdk11 right now, and `validateLocationIds(null)` gives me an explicit warning detailing exactly this. So it seems recent versions of the compiler should help with this sort of thing.

Comment: thanks @rzwitserloot for the elaborate answer! It makes much sense now that I know the method is trying to convert things to `new String[] {a, b, c}`. I'm still not sure how Intellij's Evaluate tool got it as `null` instead of `[null]` but that may require digging deeper into Intellij's way of working

Answer (score 0):

These do different things with your varargs method:

```
validateLocationIds((String)null);

validateLocationIds((String[])null);
```

The first passes a non-null array containing a null element, equivalent to `new String[] { null }`. The second passes null as the array directly.

Which of the two will happen depends on the compile-time type of your null variable.

Comment: the `var` I passed in is `String var`, so it doesn't make sense that it's converted to `[null]`?

Comment: @waynewingsyd Can you express your call in an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see it?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo you can just replace `validateLocationIdNotDeprecated(locationId);` with `souf` and simply call the function as `String var = null; validateLocationIds(var)`

Comment: @waynewingsyd Yes, exactly. `String var` will be passed as `new String[] { var }`, so if `var` is null, you get `new String[] { null }`, an array of null. That's literally precisely what it's supposed to do.